# How do I fetch a list of Facebook names from a list of Facebook IDs with one API call?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have fetched about 100 Facebook IDs from my database and stored them in a Javascript array.

For each of these, I want to fetch some data like full name, but I don't want to make over 100 API calls to do that.

What I'm using right now:

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/'+id+'?fields=id,name',function(d){ d.name; });
```

What I'm hoping exists:

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=id,name&list='+myList.join(','),function(d){ d[0].name; });
```

Or something similar using the Javascript SDK. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just provide the ID's in the querystring: Like this for the early facebook employees:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=4,5,6,7,8

I you have a lot of ID's its a good idea to limit the response to speed things up. This one gives you name+gender only:

http://graph.facebook.com/?fields=name,gender&ids=4,5,6,7,8

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way to do this and it works great:

```
FB.api('fql', { q: 'select name from user where uid in ('+mylist.join(',')+')' }, function (response) { response.data[0].name; });
```